# GWT, (simple) Websockets and 405 warnings

Tags: javascript, gwt, websocket

I'm having trouble getting basic WebSocket functionality running with GWT (2.6.0).

I'm using the default generated GWT app and GWT's built-in server, and just trying to extend the code to allow WebSocket communication. When trying to open / "upgrade" the connection, I see a 405 warning.

Source is below. When I try to connect (click on the "Connect" button), the warning appears in the Eclipse console. Sending a message and trying to close the connection do nothing at this point.

1: console message:

```
[WARN] 405 - GET /jtreeservertest/echo (127.0.0.1) 1455 bytes   Request headers  
      Upgrade: websocket  
      Connection: Upgrade  
      Host: 127.0.0.1:8888  
      Origin: http://127.0.0.1:8888  
      Pragma: no-cache  
      Cache-Control: no-cache  
      Sec-WebSocket-Key: GdLkR0qCKcRD6fvjafKNCg==  
      Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13  
      Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits, x-webkit-deflate-frame  
      User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.154   Safari/537.36    Response headers  
      Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1  
      Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store  
      Content-Length: 1455
```

2: EchoEndpoint.java:

;

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.websocket.OnError;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

import com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet;

@ServerEndpoint("/echo") public class EchoEndpoint extends RemoteServiceServlet {

    @OnOpen public void openConnection(Session session) {
        System.out.println("Connection opened: " + session);
    }

    @OnError public void onError() {
        System.out.println("error");
    }

    @OnMessage
   public void onMessage(Session session, String msg) {
      try {
         session.getBasicRemote().sendText(msg);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
   }
}
```

3: web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
              http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">

  <!-- Servlets -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>greetServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>jTreeServerTest.server.GreetingServiceImpl</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>greetServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/jtreeservertest/greet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet>
     <servlet-name>ChatServlet</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>jTreeServerTest.server.EchoEndpoint</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ChatServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/jtreeservertest/echo</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

  <!-- Default page to serve -->
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>JTreeServerTest.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

4: index.html:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jtreeservertest/jtreeservertest.nocache.js"></script>

        <script>
            var ws = null;
            function connect() {
                ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8888/jtreeservertest/echo");
                ws.onopen = function(){
                    document.getElementById("chatlog").textContent = "connected\n";
                };
                ws.onmessage = function(message){
                    document.getElementById("chatlog").textContent += message.data + "\n";
                };
                ws.onclose = function(){
                       console.log('Connection closed');
                    }
                ws.onerror = function(error){
                       console.log('Error detected: ' + error);
                    }
            }
            function postToServer(){
                ws.send(document.getElementById("msg").value);
                document.getElementById("msg").value = "";
            }
            function closeConnect(){
                ws.close();
            }
        </script>
...
```

> ```
>        <textarea id="chatlog" readonly></textarea><br/>
>         <input id="msg" type="text" />
>         <button type="submit" id="sendButton" onClick="postToServer()">Send!</button>
>         <button type="submit" id="sendButton" onClick="closeConnect()">End</button>
> <button type="submit" id="connectButton" onClick="connect()">Connect</button>
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, DevMode's embedded server doesn't support `javax.websocket`.

But even if you deployed you webapp to a servlet container that supports it, it would still fail with the same *405 Method Not Allowed* error.

This is because you `extends RemoteServiceServlet` (with no apparent reason), which only accepts `POST` requests, whereas your browser does a `GET` request with `Upgrade: websocket`.

You should either extend `javax.websocket.server.Endpoint` or just extend *nothing* and have the `@ServerEndpoint` annotation.

But even then it wouldn't be enough: your webapp would no longer start as the endpoint is not a servlet, and you declared it in `<servlet>` in the web.xml. You should either rely on classpath scanning, or deploy your websocket endpoint from a `ServletContextListener`; see https://tyrus.java.net/documentation/latest/index/deployment.html